# Match and Index functions using different workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I work in a production facility and we calculate production results on a shift by shift basis daily.  We have 11 different workbooks that we use and I want to make one shift report that will pull information from all 11 workbooks only if information is entered into those workbooks on a shift/ daily basis.

The current formula is used and works very well, but It won't return multiple lines of orders if more than 1 order is run in that specific shift/ day:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('U:\Packaging Data Collection\Individual Lines\[Line 5 - Packaging Data Collection Sheet.xlsm]MainData'!$E:$E,MATCH(B2&D2,INDEX('U:\Packaging Data Collection\Individual Lines\[Line 5 - Packaging Data Collection Sheet.xlsm]MainData'!$A:$A&'U:\Packaging Data Collection\Individual Lines\[Line 5 - Packaging Data Collection Sheet.xlsm]MainData'!$C:$C,),0)),"")
```

If two orders were run on line 5, I would want it to show both orders and not just the last order that was entered in a list.

Can you help? If you need more info or anything please let me know.

Thanks

-Adam

Comment: You can do it with some complex array formula, but considering your already complicated structure I wouldn't go for it. I'd consider other tool, like MS Acces.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for Power Query, a free add-in from Microsoft. You can combine data from several Excel workbooks, filter out rows you don't need and use the resulting list for reporting.

Once set up, a query can be refreshed and will pull the latest instances of the data sources specified.

A query can be defined with variable parameters, for example a start and end date (if you only want to use data in a certain time range).

A lot of Power Query functionality can be defined with ribbon clicks and dialogs. For more involved manipulations, the underlying M language is a powerful tool.

The web has many resources for Power Query, which is built into Excel in version 2016.